# cancel one Alamofire download request with a specific url

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have table view that download video file for each cell. Here is my code for downloading video file.

```
 func beginItemDownload(id:String,url:String,selectRow:Int) {

    let pathComponent = "pack\(self.packID)-\(selectRow + 1).mp4"

    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
      let directoryURL: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
      let folderPath: URL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Downloads", isDirectory: true)
      let fileURL: URL = folderPath.appendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
      return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }
    let url = URL(string:url)

    Alamofire.download(
      url!,
      method: .get,
      parameters: nil,
      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
      headers: nil,
      to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

          if progress.fractionCompleted < 1 {

             print(Float(progress.fractionCompleted))

          }

          if progress.fractionCompleted == 1 {
            print("Completed")
          }
        }

      }).response(completionHandler: { (defaultDownloadResponse) in

        if let destinationUrl = defaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL  {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    print("destination url -****",destinationUrl.absoluteString)

          }
        }
        if let error = defaultDownloadResponse.error {
          debugPrint("Download Failed with error - \(error)")         
          return
        }
      })
  }
```

When tapping download button for each tableview cell I can download video file and assign progress value for each cell. But now I want to cancel download request for this cell when tapping on cancel button in each cell, . 
I search different solution for this issue but I can't find any solution for cancelling one request with a specific url string. How can solve this issue. 
Thanks for all reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not tested but should work, use `originalRequest`(which is the original request when the task was created) or optionally `currentRequest`(which is the request currently being handled) to locate the specific task you want cancel:

```
func cancelSpecificTask(byUrl url:URL) {
    Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.getAllTasks{sessionTasks in
        for task in sessionTasks {
            if task.originalRequest?.url == url {
                task.cancel()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Or only cancel download task:

```
func cancelSepcificDownloadTask(byUrl url:URL) {
    let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default 
    sessionManager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in 
    for task in downloadTasks {
            if task.originalRequest?.url == url {
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: request url is same for all request , parameter is different ! is any way to check the request with parameter or any other way

Answer (score 1):

Though [luiyezheng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47959331/2305175) is really good and should do the job it is sometimes overlooked by developers (by me for example) that `Alamofire.download()` actually returns `DownloadRequest` which could be stored somewhere if needed and later `cancel()` `ed:

```
let request = Alamofire.download("http://test.com/file.png")
r.cancel()
```